# Trying to remove database name from sql file

Tags: regex, sed, sqlite

I'm trying to import a postgres dump into a sqlite3 database.
Now *pg_dump* add the database name to the expressions and this is not good for sqlite3.

```
CREATE TABLE dbname.table
```

Is it possible to tell sqlite3 to ignore database name? 
The next solution is to try to write a regexp that modifies the sql file but I'm not a regexp magician, I've obtained something along the lines of:

```
printf "\nCREATE TABLE dbname.data;\nINSERT INTO dbname.data VALUES (\"the data in dbname.\")\n" | sed -e '/^CREATE TABLE/s/dbname.//g' -e '/^INSERT INTO/s/dbname.//g'
```

But this is incorrect cause I want to substitute only the first occurrence...

Can you give me some suggestion?

Comment: If you want to remove the first occurrence on a line [remove the `g` flag](https://ideone.com/fHvaoo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't have to change your file of SQL statements:

```
$ sqlite3
sqlite> ATTACH 'your_database.db' AS dbname;
sqlite> .read dump_file.sql
```

[ATTACH](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) will open a database using the schema name `dbname` so that `dbname.tablename` will refer to it.